# Asus 6950 system crash during driver installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, amd-radeon

I recently purchased an ASUS HD 6950 DirectCU II. After booting for the first time into Windows 7 64-bit, the boot screen showed fine, and Windows loaded as expected. During the installation process of the drivers on the disk, the screens went blank and wouldn't come back on even after twenty minutes.

I restarted the machine, and after reaching the 'Windows loading screen', it simply turns itself off. The boot screens show fine.

Is this a sign of a faulty card, or a corrupted driver installation? My previous card was an NVIDIA; could drivers from that be causing conflicts here?

I'm installing it on an ASUS P5N-D motherboard with an Intel Core 2 quad-core Q6600 CPU if this helps at all. If you need any other system information, I will provide what I can.

Comment: Have you tried starting in safe mode (press F8 to get the option when Windows starts). You can then uninstall the Nvidia drivers and install the drivers for the new card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not uninstall the nvidia driver that could be a problem. Furthermore next time install the drivers from the [AMD site](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx).

Comment: I restarted in safe mode, whereby windows repaired itself. I uninstalled all drivers and started again, which solved all problems, briefly. Thanks for your help